# Transform dataframe from request into structured format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a request from a website stored in a dataframe with one column that looks like this (each line is a new row):

```
request
{"Title":"Birds","Year":"2019","Rated":"R","Runtime":"122 min"}
{"Title":"Chernob","Year":"2019","Rated":"R","Runtime":"111 min"}
{"Title":"Fame","Year":"2019","Rated":"R"}
```

I would like to transform this dataframe into another dataframe like this:

```
Title    Year    Rated    Runtime
Birds    2019    R        122 min
Cherno   2019    R        111 min
Fame     2019    R        NaN
```

Is this possible? I have tried with Pandas but cannot find a function to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Why would you assume this? I posted that I tried with Pandas and this is only one small part of the whole analysis, so I provided reproducible example and the failed approach. The question was answered with a Pythonic and elegant solution (I was not aware of map would solve the issue).

Comment: Are the contents of `request` actually strings?

Comment: Yes, those come from a web scrapping request, the solution provide by cs95 works as expected

Comment: Each one is the result of a different request? How do you make the requests? Are they actually JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the strings, then unpack with `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import ast 
pd.DataFrame(df['request'].map(ast.literal_eval).tolist())    

     Title  Year Rated  Runtime
0    Birds  2019     R  122 min
1  Chernob  2019     R  111 min
2     Fame  2019     R      NaN
```